# Where clause based upon the null and non null column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table

```
ID | col1 | col2
-------------------------
1  | val1 | val2    
2  | val1 | null
3  | val1 | val3
4  | val5 | null
```

Client will always pass valid col1 and col2 values to select single row where col2 might not exist in table. So if col2 is available than it should return the row with provided col2 otherwise return row which contain col2 = null and col1

```
return  ID = 2  if col1 = val1 and col2 = val10 
return ID = 3 if col1 = val1 and col2 = val3
```

How can this be accomplish with single SQL query?

Comment: Did you try the CASE..WHEN statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work. Without top 1 the query may select 2 rows so I order it to return the one where col2 is not null first.

```
select top 1 * from table1 
where col1 = @param1 and (col2 is null or col2 = @param2)
order by case when col2 is null then 1 else 0 end
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from table1 where col1 = @col1 and col2 = @col2
union
select * from table1 as t where col1 = @col1 and col2 is null
and not exist (select * from table1 as c where c.col1 = t.col1 and c.col2 = @col2)
```

i'm not sure if the solution with top 1 is faster, sometimes ordering is very slow.